# tflite model - model buffer empty

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

I am using [tensorflows model maker](https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb)  on a raspberry pi 4 following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZyFYniGUsw) and when I use the program *python detect.py --model shirts.tflite* I get the following error

To me, it seems I am not opening the camera properly but I am not sure how to fix this. The commands *python detect.py* and *python detect.py --model efficientdet_lite0.tflite* both work.

I am providing a screenshot of the directory for further understanding.
[image]

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi $ python detect.py --model shirts.tflite
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-wheel-hwcmjluw/opencv-python_dc56ddd000dd4893b1f852d88d4a5959/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect.py", line 137, in main
    run(args.model, int(args.cameraId), args.frameWidth, args.frameHeight,
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect.py", line 61, in run
    detector = ObjectDetector(model_path=model, options=options)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/object_detector.py", line 116, in __init__
    displayer = metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(model_path)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata.py", line 719, in with_model_file
    return cls.with_model_buffer(f.read())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata.py", line 732, in with_model_buffer
    raise ValueError("model_buffer cannot be empty.")
```

Would this question be better off at raspberrypi.stackexchange.com?